# Invocation or evocation?

Tags: meaning

The context is a report from antiquity of a priest summoning a daimon. I'd like to know if I should write 'evocation' or 'invocation' in the blank in the following sentence or if, in fact, both are correct?

Porphyry mentions that Plotinus had “as an indwelling spirit a being of the more divine degree” and he gives a detailed account of its _______ in the temple of Isis in Rome.

---

Edit: I realise from Weather Vane's answer that I should add that the spirit was made visible to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](https://www.geek.com/culture/demon-evocation-1704967/) describes the difference between evocation and invocation:

> In the simplest terms, to evoke a demon is to bring it into existence in the real world, while invocation sees a demon brought inside of the person summoning it.

The article goes on to elaborate on this simple explanation.

But it is not entirely clear from the question, because you mention "an indwelling spirit" and also "in the temple of Isis". But if we take the former, with the setting being the latter, then the sentence would be:

> Porphyry mentions that Plotinus had “as an indwelling spirit a being of the more divine degree” and he gives a detailed account of its **invocation** in the temple of Isis in Rome.

**Edit:**
OP has added that the demon was made visible, in which case it would be an **evocation**.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty helpful. With that definition, I think it's an evocation In the context. I realise too that I should edit the question to say that the spirit was made visible to others.